# Through what potential difference would an electron need to be accelerated for it to achieve a speed of 28.0% of the speed of light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Through what potential difference would an electron need to be accelerated for it to achieve a speed of 28.0% of the speed of light, starting from rest? 
So
Initial speed = 0
Final speed = .28C
So ΔU = .5 * mass of electron * final speed^2
ΔV = ΔU / q
This gave an answer of 20.1 kV but was incorrect, since the electron is moving very fast would I have to do something to account for relativistic speeds?

Comment: "would I have to do something to account for relativistic speeds?" Yes, but since you don't seem to know about how that works, you should learn this first. It's no use plugging in numbers in a formula to get the right answer, at least that's not what physics is about.

Comment: k, ill read the chapter in my book on Relativity

Comment: @mike, Out of curiosity, what level of learning are you in?  That is, what is your year in high school  or college?

Comment: senior high school physics C - Relativity is not in the curriculum

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).